# Noun instead of gerund 'expecting'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What noun can be used instead of the gerund  *expecting*? Users below have suggested  [expectancy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expectancy), but  neither its definition nor [expectation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expectation)'s, mentions pregnancy.

I ask **not** about synonyms/alternatives (eg *pregnant* and *pregnancy* [don't apply for both parents](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/107141/50720)).

> [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22your+expecting+a+baby%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22your+expecting+a+baby%22) offered [this example](http://books.google.com/books?id=sYgq6xZqfMEC&pg=PA224&dq=%22your+expecting+a+baby%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gOVQVNycGIPPmwXVsIKQDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22your%20expecting%20a%20baby%22&f=false): He was the first to break the news about your **expecting a baby**. There, you'll soon be a mother, and yet you keep on complaining that you can't get on with him

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95316/is-pregnant-couple-proper-terminology

Comment: @Josh61 I want to use 'expecting' though, not pregnant?

Comment: OED has this *noun* definition B.1 for ***expectant** - one who expects an arrival, occurrence, etc.; one who looks to receive something.* I can't see any reason why the *expectant couple* can't be referred to as the *expectants* in contexts where it's obvious the "thing expected" is a *baby*. Nor can I see anything wrong with referring to the couple's state as ***expectancy*** (of having a baby).

Comment: Although there is still some confusion. First you state you are looking for "'expecting' couple", for which Colin Fine gave an answer. Then you give examples with "expecting a baby.child". These two are not interchangeable: _He was the first to break the news about your expecting couple_ makes no sense. So which one do you want?

Comment: @oerkelens I meant to ask about `expecting a baby/child`, so 'expecting couple' concerns a couple who is `expecting a baby/child`. I'd like the noun for `expecting a baby/child`

Comment: Also, tee-hee for expecting a velociraptor on the link. Also, congrats on their fertility, their procreative accomplishment, spawning, breeding.

Comment: Assuming that people read that you want indeed specifically a noun-form of the participle "expecting" and that an answer that actually gives you an _exact_ replacement for the bold phrases in your example is considered an non-useful answer, I can only conclude that you are either looking for something that can be looked up easily widely available resources (a noun form of a verb) _or_ it is totally unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Anyway, Upvote, if you think my answer is _too_ much out of the box and indeed not useful, please say so and I will gladly remove it. Please do edit your question making it really clear what you mean to ask, because there is now plenty of evidence that _that_ is not clear yet. Just give the sentence you want to use, and tell us exactly which part you want to replace. If it has to be a noun-form of "expecting", the question is purely simple grammar and off-topic. It does seem to be a common interpretation of your question as it stands, though.

Comment: "Congrats on the addition to your family"?

Comment: @oerkelens Thank you again. I apologise for the confusion, but I've once again tried to elucidate my question. Better?

Comment: The question looks like you want the noun form for expecting, which can be applied to a couple who are about to be become parents. The related noun forms are *expectancy*, *expectation* and *expectant*. The last one fits. See @Marv Mills answer.

Comment: Sometimes, there **just isn't another word** which you can simply drop into a sentence. If that's the case (which it seems to be with *expecting* = *pregnant*) then to avoid the undesirable word it's necessary to recast the sentence entirely.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase that comes to mind is "parents-to-be".

Comment: or 'future parents'

Comment: It is a pity this one cannot be used in the example sentences as "expecting a baby"... unless you turn it into "I congratulate you on being parents-to-be", which sounds awkward. It _is_ a good expression for the _expecting couple_ though!

Comment: "Parents-to-be" sounds perfect for a couple's first child, but would it also work for parents expecting subsequent births?

Comment: I think it would still work in that case.

Answer (score 3):

"Expectant" is a word that is commonly used and applied individually each parent or to the couple together as in:

- Expectant mother
- Expectant father
- Expectant couple

Comment: As a British English speaker, I would happily say "Congratulations to the expectant couple".

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations to the new couple on their *pregnancy*.

Comment: That contradicts the (correct) observation from the OP: "'pregnant/pregnancy' can't be used for both parents"

Comment: "we're having a baby" "we're expecting" meh. They likely created the pregnancy together. I admit it's not perfect, but then it's rare that any SWA is going to be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't offer the noun form for "expecting couple" or "expecting a baby" but two suitable alternatives which have been around a while.

> Congratulations to the  **prospective parents**!
>   and
>   Congratulations to the **newly-parents**!

- [newly parents](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22newly%20parents%22&tbm=bks)
- [prospective parents](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22prospective%20parents%22)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit out-of-the box, but an expression that can be used is

> Let me congratulate you guys on your *good news*!

You could even simply use *news*, which would make it truly a one-word expression.

Good news, or *great news* can mean many things for a couple (getting a job, getting a house, getting married) but when they have recently found out they are expecting a baby, it is not uncommon that *nothing* else is as good news as the news about that pregnancy.

So, yes, the applicability of *good news*, (or *great* or *fantastic*, or even just plain *news*) depend very much on context, but that is normally not a problem - unless you have a habit of going around congratulating random people on their going to have a baby.
In the latter case, do *not* congratulate random people on occasion of the great news!

---

As an afterthought, there may even be a *zero-word option*:

> Let me congratulate you guys!

Most expectant parents will immediately assume what it is you are congratulating them with - the same way you do not have to specify to newly-weds right after the ceremony that your congratulations relate to their new marital status!

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? An explanation may raise the quality of the answer, an anonymous downvote has no positive effects whatsoever :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't really answer the question, but rephrases it, which seems more comment-like.

Comment: @SrJoven This is a SWR. The OP gives an example sentence, in which I replace the phrase he wants rephrased by a different phrase, as asked. I propose a single-word option as well. How does that _not_ answer the question, and how does rephrasing the example sentence with a different expression **ever** not answer a question of this kind?? You are basically proposing I'm gathering downvotes for answering an SWR... you may be right as some people seem to hate them :)

Comment: @SrJoven I feel dumb, but I really don't know where you are going with those 'raptors.

Comment: To clarify, I didn't downvote.