# Is it OK to say "The situation is pregnant with a crisis"?

Tags: word-usage, translation

I am translating a sentence to English that literally means:

> The world seems to be pregnant with an environmental crisis.

By looking up *pregnant* in dictionaries like [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pregnant) and [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pregnant), I found no example usage similar to my sentence.

Coming from the source language, I find it natural and it means that there is potential environmental crisis coming up in future for the world, but I am afraid this might sound weird in English.

As an alternative, I can write for example:

> The world is moving toward an environmental crisis

However, I am curious if there is any usage for pregnant as mentioned in the first sentence in English literature and if it is legal from grammatical point of view.
 Any tips?

Comment: Since a crisis is something that is immediate and critical, 'pregnant' does not, to me, sound conceptually correct. The crisis would be the birth. What led up to it, is something else. I prefer your own sentence, myself, for conceptual reasons.

Comment: I would say no until "a" is removed thus rendering "pregnant with crisis"

Comment: It's pretty metaphorical but it works.

Comment: I dislike it with *seems to be*. Metaphorically, *pregnant* is used when expectations are pretty darn high. If you want to retain the *seems to be*, I suggest *seems to be on the verge of*, as in @David 's answer.

Comment: In Italian "**in attesa**" means *waiting* (sometimes with *bated breath*) but it can also means "to be waiting with child" = [EXPECTANT](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/in%20attesa). I would look at the different meanings of the word in your native language and move on from there. A good bilingual dictionary will not provide only one interpretation.

Comment: I sounds __terribke__.  Even at the metaphical level it is off. A preganancy is bound for an actual outcome, not a 'crisis'.

Comment: "*Pregnant with FOO*" is definitely an archaic term from a time when people didn't get triggered so easily.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with people being triggered. It's just not an expression most modern English speakers would find natural.  After all, English speakers also say "annoying as fuck" and few people get triggered at that.

Comment: I would like to add another perspective. The word 'world' can have many different connotations; the 'natural world' referring purely to the earth/air/seas/nature without humanity, i.e. where it would make sense to say something like 'imagine a world without homo sapiens'. V.s. 'the world' as an inclusive term for all of humanity plus its environment. To me, your second sentence seems to imply the latter for 'world'. This is probably more fitting, considering the impending environmental crisis is almost certainly caused and catalysed by human activity. In fact, it is our crisis both from origin

Comment: and the effects it is having/will have on agriculture, freak weather etc. It literally is/will be a crisis for humanity. On the other hand the first sentence seems to imply that it is something natural and unavoidable. Timely and predictable as well. I suspect that the aim of the source you are translating is to educate people and/or motivate them to take action, in which case the suggestions 'is on the verge of', 'lies an impending crisis' are more appropriate from a psychological standpoint.

Comment: What is the source language? Can we have the original phrase or a similar one?

Answer (score 33):

Depends what you mean by OK. It is grammatical, the meaning is apparent, and you would not be thrown in gaol for writing it. And (written later) I see that @Wilk has found some examples of “pregnant with crisis”.

However I would not write it myself as I find it rather forced and unnatural. Perhaps the psychological basis of this is a positive association of pregnancy with life, rather the negative crisis. The sort of metaphor I would use for a latent crisis would be something like:

> **Seething under the surface** lies an impending crisis

Clearly it depends on the literary style of the original, but if I were translating it into English, if at all possible, I would abort the pregnancy and write something straightforward, like:

> The world is **on the [verge](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/verge) of** an environmental crisis.

or

> The world is **on the [brink](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/brink) of** an environmental crisis.

I would try to translate the idea, not the individual words.

Comment: "I would try to translate the idea, not the individual words." Wow, that's a very concise distinction. I see too many of my classmates do the former -- I might have to steal this from you.

Comment: @JonathanLam — Feel free. Someone must have said it before.

Comment: This is a superb answer, and you captured why the metaphor "pregnant with <something bad>", although technically valid, conjures up Ridley Scott's *Alien* series. More usually seen as *pregnant with hope/ opportunity/ some other good thing*.

Comment: @David Indeed they have – it’s a core tenet of translators everywhere that their job is to translate ideas, not words. :-)

Comment: @Janus Translators undertaking 'word for word translation' / 'literal translation', 'the rendering of text from one language to another one word at a time with or without conveying the sense of the original text'  [[The Online School for Freelance Translators](https://translatorthoughts.com/2016/02/word-for-word-translation/)], are obviously operating under a different core tenet. I don't know how everywhere they get.

Comment: @Edwin In my experience, not everywhere at all. I’m sure they exist, but they are thankfully a (small) minority within the world of translators. I’ve never met one.

Comment: @Janus I'm clueless about other spheres, but Bible translations into English range from the 'close-to-a-literal' variety to admitted paraphrases. It's amusing to see _pajamas_ and _boomerang_ in at least one version, while _Trinity_, as far as I know, doesn't make an appearance.

Comment: @smci — Thanks for the compliment. I don't know about *Alien*, in my day it was *Rosemary's Baby*.

Comment: Another book that talks about the translation problem, but oriented towards a lay audience and considering it as a proxy for how we think, is [Surfaces and Essences: Analogy as the Fuel and Fire of Thinking](https://books.google.com/books?id=XkQT5eTnurYC)

Answer (score 13):

I would not write pregnant with *a* crisis, but simply "**pregnant with crisis**".  Google books turns up this usage a lot.  Example -

[Against the grain, Terry Eagleton 1985](https://books.google.com/books?id=9p5ZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22pregnant+with+crisis%22&dq=%22pregnant+with+crisis%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiexLeTiY3jAhVRZM0KHbKtCl8Q6AEIVDAJ)

> 'Modernism' as a term at once expresses and mystifies a sense of one's
>   particular historical conjuncture as being somehow peculiarly pregnant
>   with crisis and change.

It is only ever "pregnant with crisis".  My google turned up many instances of that but never with any modifier of crisis: not "pregnant with * crisis".  Except "pregnant with sickle cell crisis" which is another thing completely.

Comment: If you pursue the '7000+' examples that Google announces, very soon the list dwindles to about 20 meaningfully different examples. Google searches need handling with care. / The example you give seems far from plain English.

Comment: +1 When you say "a crisis", you are referring to a particular crisis. When you just say "crisis", you're talking about the abstract concept of crisis. "pregnant" in this figurative sense applies to abstract concepts such as "danger", not actual instances of things.

Answer (score 4):

As an English speaker, I think a better word is [gestating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gestate).

- The world seems to be gestating an environmental crisis.

Gestating implies pregnancy, but also that something is growing but not yet happened.

How about changing the metaphor? I doubt pregnancy is pertinent to the context.

- The world seems to be brewing an environmental crisis.
- The world seems to be racing towards an environmental crisis.

Both of the above sentence imply that something is actively going on now. Not like "if you fall you're going to get hurt." If you don't fall then you don't get hurt.

Comment: Hello Max. Don’t you mean as a scientist? Ask people on the street in Britain or the US what gestating means. In Glasgow they would probably punch you on the nose.

Comment: While the whole concept is nonidiomatic in English, I think you've found a really good alternative if OP wants to preserve the literal wording while using one that sounds less awkward and out-of-place in English.

Comment: Yes, I speak the "American English", not real English. :-)

Comment: Not sure who your last comment is aimed at. I personally recognize without prejudice that American English differs from British English. But I doubt that any of Mark Twain, Henry James or John Steinbeck’s characters gestated any more than they intuited.

Comment: I use to work for IBM. Had a guest speaker at an after hours computer club. He was teased about his accent. He retorted with a grin "At least I speak real(!) English." // The point was I have no idea how weird a lot of phrases sound to the British. "Pregnant with" in the sentence just sounds really really weird to me.

Comment: @MaxW interesting story :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not on board with this.  While also correct, I feel that many English speakers, even (maybe especially) in America would not really understand.  It's a good term, but probably not as widely readable as "pregnant with..."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is idiomatic:

***[pregnant with (something)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pregnant+with+meaning)***

> Full of, or fraught with, or having a lot of something.
>
> - Just before naming the guilty party, he gave a pause that seemed pregnant with meaning, and I wondered whether he was telling me the truth.
> - Her speech was pregnant with emotion, and her eyes brimmed with tears as she spoke.

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: Yes, but not when combined with "elemental crisis".

Comment: @ikegami why not?

Comment: I meant "an elemental crisis". Like you said, it's *pregnant with (something)", not "pregnant with a (something)". One could use "pregnant with crisis" to mean full of crisis --and it seems that a small amount of web pages do-- but not to mean that a crisis is about to happen. It seems that "pregnant with" means "about to come into existence" in the language from which the OP is translating, but it doesn't mean that in English (as you pointed out).

Comment: One can't use a dictionary definition to justify just anything that seems to comply with it. '... pregnant with radiators / paperclips / temperature ...' are obviously ludicrous. But even more reasonable candidates ( '... pregnant with a new offer / a future of doom / an environmental crisis ...') may be far from acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

ripe for (something) [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ripe+for)

> In the condition that most invites or calls for something to happen, or particularly ready or in need of something.

Example

> The world seems to be *ripe for* an environmental crisis.

Answer (score 2):

The original source appears to be using pregnancy as a metaphor.
The author has in mind a particular environmental crisis that is developing and will come into full existence at some future time.
Metaphorically, that crisis is gestating within the world,
and the world with give birth to that crisis at that future time.

The problem in translation is that there already is a figure of speech in English
that uses the words "pregnant with," and it conflicts with the metaphor.
The Free Dictionary definition of this phrase has already been cited;
as shown in the examples given for that definition,
"pregnant with" is expected to be used with an abstract noun such as 
**meaning** or **emotion**, or **possibility**.

Compare this passage from the definition of **conceive** at
[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/conceive):

> Latin roots for conceive (by way of French) point to "take into" either "the womb" or "the mind." An idea is sometimes called "a seed" or "the seed of an idea," and conceive means to produce something from inside the mind — or to become pregnant. Another expression is "pregnant with ideas" or "pregnant with possibilities," ...

Now see how this figure of speech sets the reader's expectations:
we expect it to be followed by something abstract and uncountable (such as **meaning**) or some numerous collection of things (such as **possibilities**).
So it is very jarring to suddenly be presented with a single, specific thing
(the particular environmental crisis with which the author is concerned)
as the thing the world is pregnant with.
Because of this, I think the literal translation is likely to be misunderstood.

Perhaps you can come at the same metaphor using different phrasing:

> The world seems to be due to give birth to an environmental crisis.

Comment: “Due to”?  I would say “about to” is more natural English.

Comment: @David People often refer to a due date of a pregnancy or say a woman is due to give birth at some future date. If the due date is in the next few days, or the woman is already in labor, one could also say “about to give birth.” Since the question did not indicate how much longer the metaphorical pregnancy was expected to last, I used the less specific phrasing. Of course, the translation could use the more specific “about to” if it fits the context of the passage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there already is a closely-equivalent expression in the English language which you can use in this case. The expression, however, is not "pregnant with", but **"pregnant for"**.

You can see an example of it in use here:

> "[the situation is pregnant for an accident with these conditions](https://badgerherald.com/news/2011/03/21/bikes-may-be-denied)" (*The Badger Herald*)

This is not such a common expression, but it should be safe to use, as your readers who are quite well-read will recognize it and have no problem with it at all, and your readers who are not so well-read are probably already used to being confused by things they read anyway.

If you ultimately choose to avoid use of the word "pregnant", the next best choice is **"ripe for"**, already suggested by another user [herein](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/503490/44619).

If you do a web search for the words "pregnant for change" (in quotes, of course), you will see that this specific variant of the expression is actually fairly commonly used.

**Edit:**
I don't yet have enough reputation points to comment on anyone else's post here, so I am limited to this space, but...
for those herein who are suggesting **"pregnant with ..."**, although we certainly have that usage in English, the meaning doesn't match what the OP is looking for. "Pregnant with" implies that the thing ALREADY has this trait, and in abundance. To suggest that a thing is in a state such that something is likely to soon occur, though, "pregnant with" would not be used. As I have already stated **"pregnant for"** is what you want in that situation. (Or "ripe for" if you prefer.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't beat David's answer (translate the idea, not the words), but there is another reason to avoid the word *pregnant*. I would avoid anything that could be perceived as sexist. Political correctness is important in many countries.

Comment: That sounds hypersensitive to me.  Mentioning pregnancy is no more sexist than is mentioning beards.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with those that note that this sounds slightly odd to a native speaker.

But as part of an extended metaphor, it would come across just fine:

> The world seems to be pregnant with an environmental crisis.  The moment of its birth will signal death for all we hold dear.

although here "seems to be" would feel too weak.

Comment: Other than Alien movies, when does birth signify everyone else dying?

Comment: The only point was that in pairing "pregnant" with "birth" the slight oddity of the use of "pregnant" seems to vanish.  Perhaps "Its birth will begin an overwhelming catastrophe," instead?

Answer (score 1):

It's awkward the way it's written

> The world seems to be pregnant with an environmental crisis.

*'pregnant'* tends to be something you are or aren't, so you're weakening it with *'seems to be'*. While the idea of *'pregnant'* does get across that we're waiting for the action to happen, it would work better as a definitive statement, combined with an adjective indicating we're waiting for something to happen. We should shift that uncertainty to the even itself

> The world *is* pregnant with *many potential* environmental crises

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it's as universally awkward in English as many are making it out to be.  *"Pregnant"* has precisely this usage, and other usages that don't specify something positive, as noted by other answers.

From the simple [`pregnant pause`](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14437/what-does-pregnant-pause-mean), as in "Mid-conversation, a sudden full *pregnant pause* exclaimed the awkwardness of the meeting," to [`pregnant with fear`](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS830US830&ei=7igaXZ3tDY-utQbb6KG4BQ&q=%22pregnant%20with%20fear%22&oq=%22pregnant%20with%20fear%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1558.1558..1704...0.0..0.0.0.......0....1..gws-wiz.FCkG2O8R6gI), which definitely has a negative connotation.

There's [`pregnant with life`](https://newrepublic.com/article/151988/life-emerge) not even meaning an animal pregnant with offspring. How about [`pregnant with disaster`](https://nationalinterest.org/article/reflections-of-a-repentant-sinner-1016) (though the source isn't a personal preference).

[`Pregnant with calm`](https://www.flickr.com/photos/internetarchivebookimages/14590291458/), as in:

> The hills have no ruggedfeatures; they are softened with foliage and thewhole place is pregnant with calm beauty andrestfulness.

In fact, search Google for `"Pregnant with [...]"` using the double quotes and replacing [...] with all manner of noun, and you're sure to find examples of this usage.  While one single term, e.g. `pregnant with crisis` may itself not be extremely common, the usage with various nouns actually seems to be.